# KeyCloak - How to change "/auth/realm/<realm_name>" to "/<realm_name>"?

Tags: keycloak

Hi StackOverflow users,

I'm struggling with KeyCloak configuration because we want to change our current Identity provider to KeyCloak.

Our current solution exposes url with `/openid` prefix which causes i.e. issuer to be `HOSTNAME/openid` or event service discovery under `HOSTNAME/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

When I'm trying to use KeyCloak everything what I have achieved is `/auth/realms/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

Does anyone know how to remove `/auth/realms` prefix for KeyCloak?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of changing keycloak urls (of course that is bit difficult). What if you can put a proxy in front of your keycloak to resolve '/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration' to '/auth/realms/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Or else by changing keycloak web.xml file's

```
<web-context>auth</web-context>
```

to

```
<web-context></web-context>
```

you can get rid of "auth" part.

Comment: creating this reverse proxy will give you wrong `iss` field value inside JWT tokens